# How to keep the cache in sync with the database?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ehcache

We have database which is updating regularly. I am using ehcache and mysql database.

Now, as soon as the database is updated we need to extract some information from database depending on the update and publish it to cache.

1. How should I keep my database in sync with cache(cache should update as    database updated)?
2. How should I know when database is updated?

Comment: is database updated through the same application or different application or directly in database?

Comment: if it is same application then you know when the database will be updated.

Comment: but how should i keep my database in sync with ehcache

Comment: i think you meant ehcache in sync with database. when you know database is going to get updated, refresh your cache. If you are using spring annotations, @ CachePut or @ CacheEvict may be helpful

Comment: can u provide sample code for it?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the classical issue introduced by caching. The moment you duplicate data - in the database and in the cache - you introduce consistency issues.

There is no *single* answer to this problem.

For 1, the answer depends on how important it is to prevent stale data to be served from the cache. In some situations, this is not a problem and working with a short expiry time will solve it. In other cases, you must have up to date data in the cache and then you will have to make sure cached entries are invalidated.

Note that doing this in a fully safe way is hard, this is why [Hibernate has so many second level cache strategies](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-transactional-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/), safer and safer, but slower and slower as well.

For question 2, this is erally specific to your application. If only your application updates the database, then you *know* when to invalidate the cache. If the database is updated externally, you will have to make that system aware of your application - or at least the caches - so that it can send invalidations.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to synchronize your cache with your database but it depends upon the cache you are using.
In distributed caching following are the ways to ensure valid data in cache.

1. Using expirations(Still wont gaurantee data validity) (Feature supported by Redis,
   NCache, Apache Ignite...)
2. Using SQL, Oracle dependency (Features supported by NCache)
3. Using Custom Dependency based on notification like Cosmos and mongo db provides db change notifications (Features Supported by NCache)